How do I fix gRPC FD Shutdown error in Docker container server and pip package client?
I've deployed docker container with gRPC server on my virtual machine. Server is running on the right port, but client (packaged as pip) gives FD Shutdown when I'm trying to request from local machine:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Documents/datalake/shared-tenants-grpc/datalake_tenants_grpc/co_client.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/username/Documents/datalake/shared-tenants-grpc/datalake_tenants_grpc/co_client.py", line 49, in main
    run(channel)
  File "/home/username/Documents/datalake/shared-tenants-grpc/datalake_tenants_grpc/co_client.py", line 32, in run
    response = stub.GetData(request, timeout=100)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1181, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1006, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:20.150.212.230:9999: Failed to connect to remote host: FD Shutdown"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {created_time:"2024-05-29T17:13:45.805690845+04:00", grpc_status:14, grpc_message:"failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:20.150.212.230:9999: Failed to connect to remote host: FD Shutdown"}"

I've tried to modify timeout, it didn't help. I've tried to ping the VM - it didn't send anything back. Recently I deployed other gRPC to other VM and it did work, although second VM doesn't ping too. Address configuration seems alrighty, as in the previous server:
server.py
_LISTEN_ADDRESS_TEMPLATE = "0.0.0.0:%d"
client.py
_SERVER_ADDR_TEMPLATE = "20.160.228.245:%d"
ss -tuln has needed ports:
tcp    LISTEN  0       4096              [::]:9999           [::]:*
tcp    LISTEN  0       4096           0.0.0.0:9999        0.0.0.0:*
I've also tried to run client.py directly, not from the package and it gives the same error.
I'm trying to fix it for three days now and out of theories, what could be wrong here :(
